# Unable to compare strings while implementing Profanity filter in Unity3d

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am implementing a simple profanity filter for my player username in unity. But for some reason, I am not getting the correct result. As shown in code below, I am extracting the words from a TextAsset  .txt file into a list of strings and looping through the list to check if the username contains a badword using Contains() function. But the Contains() function is always returning false.
What else I tried :

1. Tried "==" operator to test for exact string, but still returning false
2. Tried Equals() function to test for exact string, but still returning false
3. Tried regex but still not working
   Note : both checkText and badWordToUpper are of type string and are showing right results. But when compared, not working.
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like a white char is hidden in a bad word. If you are on Windows, the break line is `"\r\n"`. You can check with :

```cs
void Start()
{
    strBlockList = ...;
    var wordWithWhiteChar = strBlockList.Where(w => w.Any(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c))).ToList();
    // Check wordWithWhiteChar
}
```

If it's the case, you need to clean each word like :

```cs
void Start()
{
    strBlockList = ...;
    for (int i = 0; i < strBlockList.Length ; i++)
    {
        strBlockList[i] = Regex.Replace(strBlockList[i], @"\s+", string.Empty).ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Bonus : To upper case in `Start` to cache the operation.

Comment: Changing "\n" to "\r\n" did the trick for me. 
Apparently, there was a whitespace character at the end of every badword.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: For more information, see : [Wikipedia - NewLine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)